# Adicionar marcador em mapa ANDROID

Tags: android, eclipse, api, android-fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

Boa noite,
tenho uma aplicação com um mapa num separador de swipe, mas pretendo que o mapa marque um ponto no mapa e inicie nesse ponto.

obrigado desde já.

Junto envio o JAVA:

```
public class Mapa extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapa_3, container, false);

    return android;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    if (f != null)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
}
```

}

e o layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map_container"
    tools:context=".Mapa" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Como está fazendo a manipulação da instância do `GoogleMap`? Para criar um marker é só criar um `MarkerOptions` e depois passá-lo ao `GoogleMap.createMarker`.

Comment: Mas isso é feito no java?

Comment: Isso mesmo, no `onCreate` da `Activity` ou do  `onCreateView` do `Fragment`. De uma olhada na primeira resposta dessa pergunta do SO EN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isso

```
private void initilizeMap() {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id. mapFragment)).getMap();

            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            createMarkers();
    }

private void createMarkers() {
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(lat, lon)).icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.pin_localizacao));
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);


 }
```